# "checkout_submit_all_after" and "sales_order_place_after" event

Tags: magento2

Anybody can explain what is the difference between "checkout_submit_all_after" and "sales_order_place_after" event in magento2

Answer (score 2):

**checkout_submit_all_after**

It runs after the order is submited successfully. It will fire both for frontend /admin order.

**sales_order_place_after**

This event called only once and when an order is successfully placed. sales_order_place_after is not proper, bcoz it is not fired every time.

sales_order_place_after naturally fires whenever call `place()` of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and its call depend on payment method.

Comment: My doubt is , in the case rest order API ( I configured  these two event in webapi_rest). After order submission  only sales_order_place_after called and checkout_submit_all_after is not calling. I don't know why